# google sheets api filter feature not working?

Tags: python, filter, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to get the filter to work for Google sheets API4 using the example here: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/filters.

The link to their example sheet doesn't work so I created my own here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kT4UU-jvFj273psdJ_fQz5xUP1Xv3Mg9zrs9U2ydM0g/edit#gid=0. It is shared.

When I run the code that they give on the site, the sheet does absolutely nothing. Here is my code. Only the top 3 lines were added by me.

```
import custom
spreadsheet_id = '1kT4UU-jvFj273psdJ_fQz5xUP1Xv3Mg9zrs9U2ydM0g'
g = custom.APIv4()  # builds service

my_range = {
    'sheetId': 0,
    'startRowIndex': 0,
    'startColumnIndex': 0,
}
addFilterViewRequest = {
    'addFilterView': {
        'filter': {
            'title': 'Sample Filter',
            'range': my_range,
            'sortSpecs': [{
                'dimensionIndex': 3,
                'sortOrder': 'DESCENDING'
            }],
            'criteria': {
                0: {
                    'hiddenValues': ['Panel']
                },
                6: {
                    'condition': {
                        'type': 'DATE_BEFORE',
                        'values': {
                            'userEnteredValue': '4/30/2016'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

body = {'requests': [addFilterViewRequest]}
addFilterViewResponse = g.service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, body=body).execute()

duplicateFilterViewRequest = {
    'duplicateFilterView': {
        'filterId':
            addFilterViewResponse['replies'][0]['addFilterView']['filter']
            ['filterViewId']
    }
}

body = {'requests': [duplicateFilterViewRequest]}
duplicateFilterViewResponse = g.service.spreadsheets() \
    .batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, body=body).execute()

updateFilterViewRequest = {
    'updateFilterView': {
        'filter': {
            'filterViewId': duplicateFilterViewResponse['replies'][0]
            ['duplicateFilterView']['filter']['filterViewId'],
            'title': 'Updated Filter',
            'criteria': {
                0: {},
                3: {
                    'condition': {
                        'type': 'NUMBER_GREATER',
                        'values': {
                            'userEnteredValue': '5'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        'fields': {
            'paths': ['criteria', 'title']
        }
    }
}

body = {'requests': [updateFilterViewRequest]}
updateFilterViewResponse = g.service.spreadsheets() \
    .batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, body=body).execute()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On that example there are 3 request:

First, `addFilterViewRequest` that has `addFilterViewResponse` as a response.

The second one is a duplicated of the first: 
`duplicateFilterViewRequest` with response `duplicateFilterViewResponse`

The third one is `updateFilterViewRequest` with response  `updateFilterViewResponse`

The example certainly does not return nothing, but it does create the filter, you'll find them if you open your spreadsheet and at the menu: Data --> Filter Views you'll find them listed by the name you've given to them.

But you could also add the following to the code you are using:

```py
    return addFilterViewResponse
```

so this will print you the complete response for the first filter

```py
    return addFilterViewResponse['replies'][0]['addFilterView']['filter']['filterViewId']
```

This will give you the filterViewId for the filter you've created first, if you want to see it in action you can do the following:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/YOUR_SPREADSHEET_ID/edit#gid=YOUR_GID&fvid=FILTERVIEWID

Where 
`YOUR_SPREADSHEET_ID` 
`YOUR_GID` can be 0 or be the GID of your spreadsheet which you'll find it on the link.
`FILTERVIEWID` is the number you just got.

I hope this clarifies your doubts.

Comment: i see, i think i'm confusing `filter` and `filter view` a bit... i was expecting it apply a filter.

Comment: `Data --> Filter Views you'll find them listed by the name you've given to them` And how to apply it using API?